# Can someone connect/discover my AWS service/instance locally (using a private addresses)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, networking

I am not an expert in networking, so I want to get a clearer image. I have an AWS running instance, and its local network is 172.31.16.0/20 with address. I know that Amazon uses 172.31.0.0/16 CIDR to manage private addresses.

If someone does a scan on 172.31.0.0/16, could he/she discover my instance?

I tried to do it with another instance of mine and it detects it, but I am not sure if it works, for instance, I don't own because of this notion of VPC that I don't really understand.

Comment: Generally (there are edge cases where this doesn’t apply), internally, in your private network, if you have a route and your security groups permit it, then yes, someone scanning internally could find the instance. Equally, if your instance has a public IP/public DNS and your security groups permit inbound access from unknown sources, then yes someone scanning could find your instance.

Comment: @helphalump I am quoting from your comment `in your private network, if you have a route and your security groups permit it, then yes`, what did you mean by "your private network", 172.31.16.0/20 or global private one (172.31.0.0/16) ? `if you have a route` there should be a route from 172.31.0.0/16 (if I do not change my private network ip/subnet) am I wrong? `security groups permit it` would you know if it is permitted by default ? ps: I am supposing my instance is accessible from internet if it would change some details

Comment: What do you mean by `global private one (172.31.0.0/16)`? I think you are misunderstanding how VPCs work. You also mention "I knew that Amazon use 172.31.0.0/16 CIDR to manage private addresses," but that would just be the CIDR block you assigned to one or more of your VPCs when you created them.

Comment: @Mark B In fact, based on the first comment `internally, in your private network...` I understood that being in my private network (VPC) is a mandatory condition to be able to discover my instance. Now what I meant by "global private" is CIDR : even between VPCs that are included in the same CIDR routing still possible, so being in the same VPC isn't mandatory unless I am missing something

Comment: Being in the same VPC is absolutely mandatory unless you have VPC peering enabled between multiple VPCs. The CIDR of your VPC is not "global" in any sense of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traffic for private [RFC1918 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) is not routable over the Internet. No one can hit your 172.31 address across the Internet. Not from outside AWS and not from another VPC (yours or anyone else's).

VPCs are per account and are isolated from each other. You can, however, share subnets of your VPC with another AWS account within the same AWS Organization, if you choose to. You can also peer VPCs, if you choose to.

Other instances within your VPC can reach an instance in the same VPC, of course, assuming the default routing and NACLs, as can anyone on your VPC's extended network, for example if you have a VPN connection into your VPC (but I assume that's not relevant here).

Comment: public IP is not a matter for me, I am just wanting to know about private networks; you say `Other instances within your VPC can reach it` what did you mean by that? is the VPC in my case is 172.31.0.0/16 or even 172.31.0.0/16 have multiple VPC isolated from each other ? thanks in advance

Comment: Other instances within the **same VPC** can reach it. Instances in different VPCs cannot (unless those VPCs are somehow peered). VPCs are isolated from each other. That's why VPC contains the letter P (for Private).

Comment: Does a VPC is shared between multiple cloud accounts or is it proper to one user (as its name is VIRTUAL PC I suppose second choice)? or it depends on how AWS decide to manage it ?

Comment: VPCs are per account, but you can share subnets of your VPC with another AWS account within the same AWS Organization, if you choose to. AWS doesn't decide this, you do.

Comment: He said he can detect this instance from other instance which is in same vpc, Question is not how a user able to connect but question is, can a user with other aws account able to detect by querying aws CIDR  (172.31.0.0)

Comment: In fact I was able to detect two instances not mine, so I have to say there is something missing in these clarifications

Comment: @youneszeboudj I suspect you'll find that these are either your instances or perhaps ENIs dropped into your VPC to support AWS services that you are using within the VPC.

Comment: @JaikeySarraf I think you're missing the point of the first statement in my response but I've clarified it.

Comment: @jarmod sorry wrong alert, I found the current instance (the one used to scan) and the router (default route), I have a clearer idea now, thanks for your clarifications

Answer (score 1):

Simply *no*. This CIDR is for a VPC, and *your* VPC is different from another AWS user's VPC.

To allow another AWS user to access your VPC network, you need to share it manually, so if you do not share it, it is not possible for other users to detect your instance by a brute force query.

Comment: To become sure, just create another VPC, add an instance and query previous vpc instance. you would not able to :)

Comment: I did  discover two instances by scanning the CIDR ! one of them seems to be a router, the other has multiple open ports, how do you explain this?

Comment: @youneszeboudj at what IPs did you discover these 'instances' and what is your VPC CIDR?

Comment: @jarmod responded in the comments below ur response, Jaikey thanks for ur clarification!

Answer (score 1):

For public IP addresses, you definitely can be discovered.

For intern IP addresses, to the extent I know, it is a virtual network, and it is isolated from other VPCs.

Comment: Could you provide some refernces?

Comment: i am not sure about it. But AWS doc should offer enought help.